# How to truncate label in cocos2dV3.0

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

i am trying to truncate label when text becomes large but instead it got expanded from center moving to left side.

This is my snippet.

```
 CCLabelTTF *playerLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Playerdadsadsd %d",i+1] fontName:@"Helvetica-Bold" fontSize:fontSize];

        playerLabel.color =  playerColor;
        playerLabel.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",1002+i];
        playerLabel.position = ccp(playerSprite.position.x + playerSprite.contentSize.width + 10, yPos);
        playerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFit = YES;
        [self addChild:playerLabel];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, but try passing `dimensions` parameter to the init method:

```
//The label won't go out of this rectangle
CGSize rect = CGSizeMake(viewSize.width * 0.1f, viewSize.height * 0.1f);

NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Playerdadsadsd %d",i+1];
CCLabelTTF *playerLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString: text 
                                             fontName: @"Helvetica-Bold"
                                             fontSize: fontSize
                                           dimensions: rect]; // <-- Note this parameter

//.. the rest of your code..
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The label which will be updated dynamically with user name. so i want to truncate name if it is long. I tried with Dimensions, which breaks the line into multiple. But i want to show some thing like this. Playerdadsa.. . How can i achieve it.

Comment: @Anish, unfortunately I'm not aware of any class in cocos2d that will do this automatically. 

I’d tried to solve this with combination of `dimensions`, `adjustsFontSizeToFit` and `minimumFontSize` settings. Specifying dimensions to only hold 1 line and the rest of the label would be just clipped (unfortunately without ellipsis).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any intrinsic solution in cocos2d-x for truncating (with or without ellipsis) a label to fit in a specified width, so I wrote a function of my own.

This is in C++, but the logic can be copied easily to Objective-C

```
CCLabelTTF *createTruncatedLabel(const char *text, const char *fontFace, float fontSize, int width, bool useEllipsis)
{
    CCLabelTTF *ttfLabel = CCLabelTTF::create(text, fontFace, fontSize, CCSizeMake(0, 0), kCCTextAlignmentLeft);
    CCSize size = ttfLabel->getContentSize();

    if (size.width > width)
    {
        int len = strlen(text);
        float pc = (float)width / (float)size.width;
        int newLen = (int)((float)len * pc);
        size = setTruncLabel(ttfLabel, text, newLen, useEllipsis);

        if (size.width > width)
        {
            while (size.width > width)
            {
                newLen--;
                size = setTruncLabel(ttfLabel, text, newLen, useEllipsis);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while (size.width < width)
            {
                newLen++;
                size = setTruncLabel(ttfLabel, text, newLen, useEllipsis);
            }

            if (size.width > width)
            {
                newLen--;
                setTruncLabel(ttfLabel, text, newLen, useEllipsis);
            }
        }
    }

    return ttfLabel;
}

CCSize setTruncLabel(CCLabelTTF *ttfLabel, const char*text, int len, bool useEllipsis)
{
    char newText[256] = {0};

    strncpy(newText, text, len);

    if (useEllipsis)
    {
        strcat(newText, "...");
    }

    ttfLabel->setString(newText);
    CCSize size = ttfLabel->getContentSize();

    return size;
}
```